# How can I create an automatically updating chart from a different worksheet with blank spaces in excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, charts

I have a worksheet that lists every day so I can see if any tests were performed that day. If there were tests, then the average and standard deviation of that day show up in the next two columns. I also break up the days by adding rows of weekly averages.

[image]

I need to make a graph that only graphs the days averages and will automatically update if any new information is put in. As I understand it I can not use the OFFSET function because my information is not in a continuous line. The only solution I can think of is to filter out all of that information in a chart that automatically updates when new information is entered in the original worksheet, which will in turn update the graph.

How can I do this?

Comment: Check out [Make a Dynamic Chart using Data Filters](http://chandoo.org/wp/2009/02/12/make-a-dynamic-chart-using-data-filters/). There are some other great ideas at this site which might help you.

Comment: I've been watching a lot of videos on filtering charts and dynamic graphs but so far nothing is quite like my situation. The link you gave me is good. But how do I get my chart like that from the information I'm working with?

Comment: I guess what I'm having trouble with is that, I know how to make a dynamic graph from a chart, but I don't know how to make a dynamic chart from a spreadsheet.

Comment: It is difficult to help when we do not see the sheet you are working with. Can you do a screen shot or file share and place a link in the question so we can get an idea what you are working with (I know you don't have reputation to imbed a pic)?

Comment: I think the link I added works, it is a picture of the information that I am working with. I have to take what you see and create a chart that automatically updates when I put new information into this worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see in your picture, I think the easiest way to make a chart is to build a table of averages in a different sheet. Reference the weekly averages from the "Resilience" sheet to the table. Then select the data in the new table to make the chart (example below).

[image]

When you update the data on the "Resilience" sheet the table and the chart will update. In the below example I added data to the week of 10/13 and the chart automatically updated.

[image]

Keep in mind, to have things update automatically, you will need to have auto calculations enabled in options. Otherwise, press <kbd>F9</kbd> to update calculations manually.